# Drag and drop li elements using dataTransfer Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dom-events, javascript-framework

I am automating one of the drag and drop functionalities in our application. All I am trying is to drag and drop li elements from 'sourcelist' to 'destlist' through javascript using dataTransfer object. Here is what I have done and I am getting **an error in Firefox.
saying 'event.dataTransfer is undefined'**

```
<div id=source> 
  <ul id=sourcelist>
   <li title='foo1'>foo1</li>
   <li title='foo2'>foo2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id=dest>
 <ul id=destlist> </ul> 
</div>


event.dataTransfer.setData("text/html","<li title='foo1'>foo1</li>");
var textData = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
var target=document.getElementById('destlist');
target.innerHTML=textData;
```

Do I have to initialize the object event? how do I create an event object programmatically for drag and drop? I am pretty new to Javascript and would appreciate if someone could point me in right direction.

Comment: Which frameworks are you using?

Comment: My application uses jQuery so I can use jQuery to do the drag drop. Do you know how to do drag and drop in jQuery?

Comment: Please can you post all of the code?  I'm assuming that there is more - 'event' is not defined at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

DragDrop feature is supported only in the newer version of the browser. Have u tried Chrome 8, Safari 5 or Firefox 3.6. They are all new versions and it should work there.

Check following links for help.

http://html5demos.com/drag

http://html5doctor.com/native-drag-and-drop/

[enter link description here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/html5-drag-and-drop-in-deeetail)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps take a look at http://jquerypp.com/ which offers extentions to jQuery, among other for the dragNdrop challange.

Answer (score 1):

For future visitors who find this thread, as I did: some browsers only support dataTransfer for certain events. Chrome, for one, doesn't support it for dragstart or dragover, sadly.  That is probably why the OP's code fails. Found that out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7837276/597849