# How do you get the selected items from a dragstart event in Chrome? Is dataTransfer.getData broken?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

I am part of a team that works on a Java application that, among other things, helps people organize and annotate information from the web.  We currently use a Firefox plug-in that attaches a container attribute that contains a document source, which allows dragged text to become cited automatically.  This will not always result in getting the source document because only text is transferred when a selection does not cross html tags. e.g.

```
<p container="http://www.somesite.com/blah.html">this is text from a site</p><p container="http://www.somesite.com/blah.html">this is more text from a site</p>
```

So if only ***is text*** is selected, the html tags are never crossed and the browser thinks the surround tag information and its container attribute would be unwanted; so it ignores it.

So I decided to make a Chrome extension that would exploit some of the nifty features of HTML5 to make any drag from a browser page that is dropped into out Java application include the source document.  FYI, Chrome extensions are Javascript based.

The correct for thing to do, it seems, is to register a dragstart event on the document that will allow me to access the content of the drag and also let me inject a meta tag that includes the source document location.

According to the current standard, http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-datatransfer-interface , this should be possible by using the **dataTransfer** interface.

So, I register the **dragstart** event that should give me the dataTransfer event information.  You can copy and paste this code into Chrome's Javascript console to see it for yourself:

```
window.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
console.log(event.dataTransfer.types);
console.log(event.dataTransfer.getData("Text"));     });
```

Then select something and drag it.  In Chrome, the output is **"null"** then **"undefined"**.  If you paste the same code into Firebug's Javascript console then drag some text that you select, the out put is what you would expect:

```
DOMStringList { 0="text/_moz_htmlcontext", 1="text/_moz_htmlinfo", 2="text/html", more...}
whatever text was selected
```

Curiously, one *can* use setData on the event.dataTransfer to change what is dropped.  That part seems to work as expected.  Paste this instead into the Chrome Javascript console, then select something and drag it to a text editor or your search box:

```
window.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Text","I made this here for you!");
});
```

It looks like it's broken. :(  Does anyone have a workaround or some insight into this issue?  I really want this to work in Chrome because I like its extension architecture.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

WebKit, and hence Chrome, is quite restrictive on when you can call `getData`.  You're not allowed to do it inside [`dragstart` or `dragover`](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=58206#c7).  I think [this is the canonical bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23695).

Comment: Thanks.  I added a comment to what appears to be the newest bug report about this: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=58206.

Answer (score 2):

Paste this line before the error line:

```
event.dataTransfer = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
```

This worked for me.

Comment: That was the only thing that worked for me as well. Big Thanks.