# event.DataTransfer doesn't transfer ID of dragged object when running in Jetty

Tags: html, jsp, maven, drag-and-drop, jetty

I have a Maven Jetty project with JSPs using JavaScript. I want to be able to highlight parts of a canvas corresponding to the dragged image's size.

When I look at my JSP by simply opening it in the browser everything works as expected but when I start the Jetty Server with the goal jetty:run the ID of the dragged object is not being set or cannot be retrieved from the transferData of the event.

The relevant code: All draggable images have a unique ID. On drag start I set the ID of the dragged image on the event's transferData like this:

```
function dragShipFromTable(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("id",event.target.id);
}
```

When the image is dragged over the canvas I call the following function

```
function allowDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = event.dataTransfer.getData("id");
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    // Do the highlighting stuff
    ....
}
```

The problem is that when the server is started and I do the above action then in allowDrop(event) the ID of the dragged image is not being retrieved from the transferData. It is undefined and therefore the highlighting fails. This is not the case when simply opening the JSP as a File.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I kind of found the answer to my own question. First of all the setData method on the dataTransfer object only allows certain formats as first parameter. I interpreted it as an associative array but this is not the case. So it should be

```
event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", id);
event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
```

to set and retrieve the id correctly.

But in the end everything failed due to chrome as there is a bug in Chrome which prevents me from using dataTransfer as intended (see [How do you get the selected items from a dragstart event in Chrome? Is dataTransfer.getData broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830249/how-do-you-get-the-selected-items-from-a-dragstart-event-in-chrome-is-datatrans) ).

I now use global variables to store the information I need. And still I am wondering why everything worked fine when the page was displayed as a file instead of as a response from the webserver.