# How can I disable hover state on mousedown or on dragstart?

Tags: javascript, css, hover, drag

I have a list of nodes (divs) that can be re-arranged via drag-and-drop. Sample code is listed below. Normally, I want to highlight the hovered node with one class (for simplicity, let's say blue background, ":hover" pseudo class), but when a node is dragged I want to highlight with a different class (red, "dragged" class).

I'm having two problems with this:

1. In `dragstart()` I apply "dragged" class to the node, but it doesn't take the effect immediately. I *can* change the background color by modifying style.backgroundColor directly, but I was hoping there's a more straightforward css solution to redraw a node after adding a class.
2. Hover state gets messed up once I change the order of nodes. As you can see, if you drag node from top to bottom hovered state follows that node (masking "dragged" class), but if you drag from bottom to top hovered state jumps to the original index (index of the node that received mousedown) and now "dragged" class shows up.

I tried various things but to no avail. As far as I can tell there's no way to remove or suspend :hover pseudo class, and I can't figure out if there's a way to force hover on a certain node (I tried simple things like setting focus to make the node active).

The second problem is the real issue, but I would appreciate if anyone can comment on how to resolve both issues. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
.node {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 26px;
    width:300px;"
}
.node:hover {
    background-color: #4444ff;
}
.dragged {
    background-color: #ff4444;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id='cont' style="width: 300px;"></div>
</body>

<script>

(function(){
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        html += '<div id="' + i + '"draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(event)" ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragend="dragend(event)" class="node">item' + i + '</div>';
    }
    document.getElementById('cont').innerHTML = html;
})();

function dragstart(event) {
    event.target.className += ' dragged';
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', event.target.id);
}

function dragenter(event) {
    var sourceId = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    var targetId = event.target.id;

    if (targetId === sourceId) {
        return true;
    }

    var sourceNode = document.getElementById(sourceId);
    var targetNode = document.getElementById(targetId);
    var sourceIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(sourceNode.parentNode.childNodes, sourceNode);
    var targetIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(targetNode.parentNode.childNodes, targetNode);
    if (targetIndex > sourceIndex) {
        targetNode.parentNode.insertBefore(targetNode, sourceNode);
    } else {
        targetNode.parentNode.insertBefore(sourceNode, targetNode);
    }
}

function dragend(event) {
    event.target.className = event.target.className.replace(' dragged', '');
}

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: For your first issue add `!important` at the end of your `.dragged`'s `background-color`. For the second one, I think I don't clearly understand what the issue is, works fine for me on Firefox

Comment: Kaiido, thanks for your prompt reply. Adding !important indeed works for the first problem. The second problem shows up in Chrome, I just checked Firefox and there indeed it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

**First issue :**

In the CSS, add `!important` at the end of your `.dragged`'s `background-color`.

**Second issue :**

Apparently, Chrome have an [odd behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830249/how-do-you-get-the-selected-items-from-a-dragstart-event-in-chrome-is-datatrans) with `event.dataTransfer.setData()`

I just tested by replacing `setData('text/html'...` by `setData('Text'...`
and it actually does work in my Chrome (36 osx).

Of course you'll have to change the getData() parameters to `"Text"` too

### Edit from comments

Due to Chrome restrictions about `dataTransfer.setData()` I wasn't able to make a working fiddle for last code.
But it does work for me in a standalone page.

The easiest solution would be to use a global variable that will store your element.

```
var draggedItem;
function dragstart(event) {
    event.target.className += ' dragged';
    draggedItem = event.target;   
}

function dragenter(event) {
    var sourceId = draggedItem.id;
    var targetId = event.target.id;
...
```

Here is a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2Kgvh/

Comment: Kaiido, thanks again for your answer. First issue is resolved, and, furthermore, we can add `.dragged` class in mousedown instead of `dragstart` to force the repaint immediately. But I still see the second issue even with 'Text' format type - dragging node from bottom to top leaves one of the nodes in hovered state. (btw, just also learned that IE doesn't support 'text/html' type, so I might need to find a solution for IE as well.)

Comment: Hi Kaiido, it's working as far as `setData` goes, but the problem with lingering hovered node is still there in Chrome. If I drag a node up I see the previous node (one that immediately moves down) remain in 'hovered' state. Doesn't happen in Firefox.

Comment: @S.V. I added a working fiddle, check this out, do you still have the issue?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I still see the issue. If I drag an item from bottom to top, one of the items remains blue while the dragged item is red. I would've liked the blue hovered state to disappear in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This was turning into a css and cross-browser nightmare, so I resorted to jQuery and its Sortable Widget implementation.